# convert ascii json to utf8 in python

Tags: python, json, utf-8

I got this json response and I try to convert it to utf8 i tried several ways so far i did not succeeded in converting it:

```
{u'scan_id': u'ebb031c3945e884e695dbc63c52a5efcd075375046c49729980073585ee13c52-1503500953', u'sha1': u'c1f95108a34228535a9262085e784d7c3e27fc68', u'resource': u'8bd6509aba6eafe623392995b08c7047', u'response_code': 1, u'scan_date': u'2017-08-23 15:09:13', u'permalink': u'https://www.virustotal.com/file/ebb031c3945e884e695dbc63c52a5efcd075375046c49729980073585ee13c52/analysis/1503500953/', u'verbose_msg': u'Scan finished, information embedded', u'sha256': u'ebb031c3945e884e695dbc63c52a5efcd075375046c49729980073585ee13c52', u'positives': 0, u'total': 59, u'md5': u'8bd6509aba6eafe623392995b08c7047', u'scans': {u'Bkav': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'1.3.0.9282', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'MicroWorld-eScan': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'12.0.250.0', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'nProtect': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'2017-08-23.02', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'CMC': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'1.1.0.977', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'CAT-QuickHeal': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'14.00', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'McAfee': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'6.0.6.653', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Cylance': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'2.3.1.101', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'VIPRE': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'60504', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'AegisLab': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'4.2', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'K7AntiVirus': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'10.22.24389', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'K7GW': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'10.22.24356', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170821'}, u'TheHacker': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'6.8.0.5.1865', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170821'}, u'Arcabit': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'1.0.0.817', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Baidu': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'1.0.0.2', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'F-Prot': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'4.7.1.166', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Symantec': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'1.4.0.0', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'ESET-NOD32': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'15962', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'TrendMicro-HouseCall': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'9.950.0.1006', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Avast': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'17.5.3585.0', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'ClamAV': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'0.99.2.0', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Kaspersky': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'15.0.1.13', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'BitDefender': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'7.2', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'NANO-Antivirus': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'1.0.98.18752', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'SUPERAntiSpyware': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'5.6.0.1032', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Tencent': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'1.0.0.1', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Ad-Aware': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'3.0.3.1010', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Emsisoft': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'4.0.1.883', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Comodo': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'27648', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'F-Secure': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'11.0.19100.45', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'DrWeb': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'7.0.28.2020', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Zillya': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'2.0.0.3369', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'TrendMicro': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'9.862.0.1074', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'McAfee-GW-Edition': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'v2015', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Sophos': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'4.98.0', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Cyren': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'5.4.30.7', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Jiangmin': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'16.0.100', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Webroot': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'1.0.0.207', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Avira': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'8.3.3.4', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Antiy-AVL': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'3.0.0.1', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Kingsoft': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'2013.8.14.323', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Microsoft': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'1.1.14003.0', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'ViRobot': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'2014.3.20.0', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'ZoneAlarm': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'1.0', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'GData': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'A:25.13952B:25.10265', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'AhnLab-V3': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'3.10.0.18405', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'ALYac': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'1.1.1.2', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'AVware': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'1.5.0.42', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'MAX': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'2017.6.26.1', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'VBA32': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'3.12.26.4', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Malwarebytes': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'2.1.1.1115', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'WhiteArmor': {u'detected': False, u'version': None, u'result': None, u'update': u'20170817'}, u'Zoner': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'1.0', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Rising': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'25.0.0.1', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Yandex': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'5.5.1.3', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Ikarus': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'0.1.5.2', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Fortinet': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'5.4.247.0', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'AVG': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'17.5.3585.0', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Panda': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'4.6.4.2', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}, u'Qihoo-360': {u'detected': False, u'version': u'1.0.0.1120', u'result': None, u'update': u'20170823'}}}
```

I want to get rid of the u' at the begining of each item in the json .

Comment: That's not JSON, that's a Python 2 dictionary. Use `json.dumps()` to covert it to JSON.

Comment: _if_ you have control over the code which is generating the response, use `json.dumps` to create the response string.  If not, you can probably still read the string using `ast.literal_eval` (and you should probably contact the API owner and let them know to start using JSON instead of python literals).

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) built-in library which provides you with a `dumps` method that takes a valid Python dictionary object and dumps it into a JSON string representation of that dictionary.

For example:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({u'key': u'value'})
'{"key": "value"}'
>>>
```